# sorting two times based on status and title java android

Tags: java, android

Well I have a class named data:

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data>{
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String inststatus;
    public int imageId;

    Data(String title, String description, int imageId,String inststatus) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.inststatus = inststatus;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data another) {

        if(this.inststatus.equals("Present")){
            return this.title.compareTo(another.title);
        }else // Not Present
        return this.inststatus.compareTo(another.inststatus); // ascending


    }

}
```

Now if you see the class I am already comparing it based on title in ascending order but I want to do sorting on two rules

inststatus has 2 values :- "Present" and "Not Present"
1. inststatus = "Present" should come on top and after that, all of them should sort in ascending order
2. inststatus = "Not Present" should come on bottom and after that, all of them should sort in ascending order

Now let's take an example we have a list of values

```
title = abc ,status = present
title = bcd , status not present
title = xyz ,status = present
title = aac ,status not present
```

Now after the above 2 rules, it should be after sorting

```
1. abc // present and also ascending
2. xyz
3. aac // now left ones not present and also ascending
4. bcd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, inststatus is more important then title. Is that right? If it is then, first you should check inststatus and if their inststatus are same after that you should check titles. If inststatus is not same and if your object is present that means other one is not-present so you can return 1. The rest is same. If it is not present then return -1.

You can implement something as following.

```
public int compareTo(Data another){

    if(inststatus.equals(another.inststatus)){
        return title.compareTo(another.title);
    }
    return inststatus == "present" ? 1: -1;

}
```